# Change url alias for user profile pages based on role

Tags: 7, path-aliases

I have two sets of users, faculty and staff, with corresponding Profile2 profiles.

I can't figure out how to get different paths for users dependent on roles, e.g, staff/userid or faculty/userid.

I've been trying with both [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto).  Seems like it should be simple but can't get work it out.

Comment: This should be doable by implementing `hook_pathauto_alias_alter` in a module.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably try this approach. Was hoping it could be done through UI.

Comment: Another approach would be to use Page Manager (part of ctools).

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a hidden field on the user account page, and populate that field with Rules during registration. For example, for someone with the *Staff* role, give it the *staff* value; for user with the *Faculty* role, give it the *faculty* value.

Then, with the Pathauto module, define a pattern for user paths, for example *[user:XXXXX]/[user:uid]*, where XXXXX is the name of the hidden field you created, prefixed with *field*.

Comment: That seems like it could work. I solved this in a similar way, using tokens in URL Alias config (admin/config/search/path/patterns).   Rewrote path as: 'people/[user:profile-faculty][user:profile-staff]/[user:name-raw]'. Your tokens would obviously be different, depending on what fields you're calling. May be sub-optimal, but no user will be both faculty AND staff, so it works well enough.

Comment: Keep in mind a user can add a value to a hidden element, so don't rely on that method for sensitive operations.